# Microphone input volume gets lowered whenever it detects noise

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, headset

I have a Windows 10 laptop that's been encountering an issue for the past 2 months.

My mic volume will automatically lower when I speak into it while the mic was in use in another program (chrome, video game voice chat, zoom, e.t.c.). I would go into sound settings and watch the volume go down when I spoke or blew into the mic. This only happens if the mic is in use and detects noise, but it will keep lowering until my mic becomes completely inaudible (<10%). I can set it to 100 but it will still go down the moment it the mic picks up noise.

I have tried turning off "allows apps to have exclusive control", checking the "do nothing" circle in the communications tab, disabling every other recording device, uninstalling steam and skype, updating drivers, reinstalling drivers, running antiviruses, running windows troubleshooting, configuring speech recognition, switching ports, and just about every other solution I've seen, all to no avail. I have tried 3 different pairs of USB headphones but they all have the same problem when used with my laptop, so I know it's an issue with my device.

I have run out of ideas and have resorted to keeping the sound settings page open at all times so I can set the mic volume back to 100 every minute or so when I'm in a voice call.

For some reason, it seems discord does not contribute to the problem (at least, the desktop version), and I can still be in a discord call without the mic volume dropping. I haven't found any other apps to exclude.

If anyone has any idea what is going on, your advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The way you mention it, it seems analogous to Zoom's *Automatically adjust Microphone volume* option in Audio tab. But you experience it across various apps. **Q1**: Have you simply tried recording an audio clip via inbuilt windows' recorder? The second thing I know is, this isn't natural behaviour, so **Q2**: Which audio device driver dyou have?

Comment: Some audio drivers allow automatic control of microphone boost. They'll ramp up the gain when there's no sound, and then drop it when it begins picking up sound. It's been a while since I dealt with these but there's always a setting in the audio settings enabling or disabling this function, or tuning or adjusting it

Comment: I tried recording with Windows Voice Recorder and watching my mic sound bar and it didn't drop. I also went into zoom settings, turned off the automatically adjust microphone volume setting and now that works fine too. Along with it, it seems it fixed a lot of other problems. I tested everything I could think of that used a mic (steam, google meet, OBS, e.t.c.) and so far the only thing I could find that still lowered the mic volume was when I hit "mic test" on the browser version of discord.

Comment: I'm not sure why these would have anything to do with zoom (my mic volume would drop only if I had a mic application open, even if zoom was closed and exited fully). I also don't know what makes the mic test on browser discord special, but its specific enough to not be a problem.  I'll test everything again tomorrow and hopefully it'll stay the way it is now. If the problem persists I'll be back here soon. In any case, at least zoom should be fixed, so thank you very much for that!